# I am trying to write the result of the dql queries into a separate CSV file using dfc coding.

Tags: java, csv, dql, documentum, dfc

[i have attached screen shot of the resultant CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6emI.png)

I am trying to write the result of the dql queries into a separate CSV file using dfc coding. but the result of the first record is printing twice in the resultant sheet.

public class ChkGroupExistence {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
private static Properties queryProp;
//private static Properties configProp;
IDfSession sess = null;


public ChkGroupExistence() {
    System.out.println("Loading Properties..");
    LoadProps loadProp = LoadProps.getInstance();
    queryProp = loadProp.getQueryProp();
    //configProp = loadProp.getConfigProp();
    List<String> proj_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> grp_list =  new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> acl_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String, String> projList_Map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    IDfCollection projId_coll = null;
    IDfCollection grp_coll = null;
    //IDfCollection chk_coll = null;
    //IDfCollection acl_coll = null;

    String grpqry = null;

    String chkqry = null;

    //String getACLQuery = null;

    int j=0;
    CreateSession ifcDocsDfSession = new CreateSession();
    try {
        sess = ifcDocsDfSession.getSession();
        DfLogger.info(this, "Session Created ::" + sess.getSessionId(),
                null, null);
    }   catch (DfException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String qry = queryProp
            .getProperty(IdocsConstants.PROJECT_ID);
    try {
        CSVWriter csvwriter=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\WBG\\IFCTools\\cs_log.csv")));

        projId_coll = Util.executeQuery(sess, qry, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);

        while (projId_coll.next()) {
            proj_list.add(projId_coll.getString("project_id"));
        }

        System.out.println("List of Project ::"+proj_list.size());
        String tempQuery=queryProp.getProperty(IdocsConstants.P_GROUP_EXIST);
        //String tempQuery1=queryProp.getProperty(IdocsConstants.P_GROUP_VERIFY);
        //String tempQuery2 = queryProp.getProperty(IdocsConstants.P_GETACL);


        List<String[]> csvList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        List<String[]> titleList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String[] projList;
        String[] titleString;

        titleString = new String[3];

        titleString[0]="ProjectId/Institutionnbr";
        titleString[1]="GroupName";
        titleString[2]="ACL Name";

        titleList.add(titleString);
        csvwriter.writeAll(titleList);

        for(int i = 0; i <proj_list.size();i++ ) {

        //grpqry = tempQuery+proj_list.get(i) + "_ed_off_grp'" ;
        grpqry = MessageFormat.format(tempQuery,proj_list.get(i));

        //chkqry = queryProp.getProperty(IdocsConstants.P_GROUP_VERIFY);

        //System.out.println(grpqry);
        //getACLQuery = MessageFormat.format(tempQuery2, proj_list.get(i));

        //System.out.println(getACLQuery);
        //System.out.println("grp_coll query is executing....");
        grp_coll = Util.executeQuery(sess, grpqry, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);
        //System.out.println("verification query is executing.....");
        //chk_coll = Util.executeQuery(sess, chkqry, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);
        //acl_coll = Util.executeQuery(sess, getACLQuery, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);


        if (grp_coll!=null && grp_coll.next()) {

            String grpName = grp_coll.getString("group_name");
            grp_list.add(grpName);

            System.out.println("Got group for "+proj_list.get(i)+" :: "+grpName);

            projList=new String[3];

            projList[0]=proj_list.get(i);
            projList[1]=grpName;

            //System.out.println(grpName);
            projList_Map.put(proj_list.get(i),grp_list.get(j));
            j++;
            System.out.println(projList_Map.size());

            if(chkqry == null){
                //System.out.println("group names are adding to the list.....");
                //grp_list.add(grpName);

                String acl_name = queryProp.getProperty(IdocsConstants.P_GETACL); 
                acl_list.add(acl_name);
                projList[2]=acl_name;
                }

            csvList.add(projList);
            csvwriter.writeAll(csvList);
        }


    }
        System.out.println("Project List is loading....");
        Set<String> keySet = projList_Map.keySet();
        System.out.println(grp_list);
        System.out.println(acl_list);
        for(String set : keySet) {
            System.out.println(set + " : " +projList_Map.get(set));
        }



        csvwriter.close();

    } catch (DfException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    ChkGroupExistence chkexist = new ChkGroupExistence();
}
```

}

CSVWriter.java

public class CSVWriter {

```
/**
 * Default Delimiter will be used if not given.
 */
private static final char DEF_DELIM = ',';

/**
 * Default Quote Character will be used if not given.
 */
private static final char DEF_QUOTE_CHAR = '"';

/**
 * Default End of Line Character.
 */
private static final char DEFAULT_EOL = '\n';

/**
 * Contains the Delimtter.
 */
private char delimiter;

/**
 * Contains the Quote character.
 */
private char quotechar;

/**
 * String contains the End of the line character.
 */
private char cLineEnd;

/**
 * Instance Variable to hold Write Object.
 */
private Writer rawWriter;

/**
 * Instance variable to hold PrintWriter object
 */
private PrintWriter pw;

/**
 * Constructor to take File Writer as Input.
 * 
 * @param writer
 *            File Writer
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer) {
    this(writer, DEF_DELIM);
}

/**
 * Constructor to take File Writer and Delimiter as Input.
 * 
 * @param writer
 *            File Writer
 * @param delim
 *            Delimiter
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char delim) {
    this(writer, delim, DEF_QUOTE_CHAR);
}

/**
 * Constructor to take File Writer, Delimiter and Quote Character as Input.
 * 
 * @param writer
 *            File Writer
 * @param delim
 *            Delimiter
 * @param quote
 *            Quote Character
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char delim, char quote) {
    this(writer, delim, quote, DEFAULT_EOL);
}

/**
 * Constructor to take File Writer, Delimiter, Quote Character and End of
 * Line feed as Input.
 * 
 * @param writer
 *            File Writer
 * @param delim
 *            Delimiter
 * @param quote
 * @param sEOL
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char delim, char quote, char sEOL) {
    rawWriter = writer;
    pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    delimiter = delim;
    quotechar = quote;
    cLineEnd = sEOL;
}

/**
 * Method takes List as input and writes values into the CSV file.
 * 
 * @param list
 *            List of Cell values.
 */
public void writeAll(List list) {
    String sRow[];
    for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); writeNext(sRow)) {
        sRow = (String[]) iter.next();
    }
}

/**
 * Method that takes String[] as input and writes each and every cell.
 * 
 * @param sRow
 *            String[]
 */
private void writeNext(String sRow[]) {
    StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < sRow.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            stringbuffer.append(delimiter);
        }
        String s = sRow[i];
        if (s == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (quotechar != 0) {
            stringbuffer.append(quotechar);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
            char c = s.charAt(j);
            if (c == quotechar) {
                stringbuffer.append(DEF_QUOTE_CHAR).append(c);
                continue;
            }
            if (c == DEF_QUOTE_CHAR) {
                stringbuffer.append(DEF_QUOTE_CHAR).append(c);
            } else {
                stringbuffer.append(c);
            }
        }

        if (quotechar != 0) {
            stringbuffer.append(quotechar);
        }
    }

    stringbuffer.append(cLineEnd);
    pw.write(stringbuffer.toString());
}

/**
 * Method that closed the Print Writer. Only when this method is called, the
 * CSV file will be saved.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    rawWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you're including a repeating attribute in your query.

Tip: I tend to include the object ID for reference and debugging when I do this.

You can also insert a "DISTINCT" keyword into your query when including these repeating attributes.

The reason they act like this is the nature of the data model: all repeating attributes are stored in the same table - so when one of these attributes contains multiple values a query could return multiple rows when querying another repeating attribute. In this case a SELECT DISTINCT would do the trick.

You can also play around with the DQL hint ENABLE(ROW_BASED) if you are joining repeating attribute with single value attributes.

Happy coding!

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer and it should be marked as such.